# How to fix the button layout to be always visible on a rich:popup panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsf

I have a rich:popupPanel in which there can many contents.
Also there are navigation button (Cancel, Back, Save and Next) which are always displayed at the bottom based on the height of the popup as set.
If the content is bigger than height set for the popup then we get a scroll-bar as usual.

My requirement is that even if the content on the page is more than the height of the popup, I still want to display the navigation button to the user without scrolling at the bottom.

I'm using rich faces 4.x with JSF 2.x vesion.

Kindly help.

Regards,
Sandy

Comment: Hi welcome to SO you may need to read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and this http://sscce.org/ to make a good question.

Comment: code...screeshot....Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)...anythng to start with????